# Magento 2 Product quantity showing empty on Update Product details page

Tags: magento2, cart, qty

**Step to reproduce**

1. Add product to cart
2. Go to cart page
3. Click on Edit item parameter.
   [image]
4. Qty box value empty.
   [image]

Any help would be appreciated!Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be working fine, with default Magento 2.2.5 sample data. In the chrome browser. It is better if you share details like browser, Magento version, or if any customization done. It does takes a millisecond of time for the 1 to come up in qty box due to knockout may be.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue after upgrading the magento to latest version(2.2.6).

Answer (score 3):

You have to override the below path in your custom theme

Base file path :

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/configure/updatecart.phtml
```

Move To Theme file path

```
app/design/frontend/<VENDOR_NAME>/<THEME_NAME>/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/configure/updatecart.phtml
```

And add this below text in the input

```
 <?= $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>
```

Exmple:-

```
<input type="number"
   name="qty"
   id="qty"
   min="0"
   value="<?= $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
   title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>"
   class="input-text qty"
   data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. The main Reason was that js fired before the layout render. 
Check this file vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/configure/product-customer-data.js

```
productId = $(selectors.productIdSelector).val(),
```

This productId gets initial value null and after that is not reinitialized, which brakes the value population here.

```
if (!(data && data.items && data.items.length && productId)) {
    return;
}
```

We moved productId initialization to another function so it is reinitialized later when the view is rendered. 
Not a clear solution but it works

Answer (score 0):

Same bug after upgrading a 2.1 to 2.4. They changed the *product/view/form.phtml* , adding this line :

```
<input type="hidden" name="item"  value="<?= (int)$block->getRequest()->getParam('id') ?>" />
```

Never forget to check changes in custom themes, even if it's a pain...

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I disabled extension "php bin/magento module:disable BoostMyShop_AdvancedStock" and stock issue resolved.

Thanks,